# What is the better(or more common) notation to show square of logarithm?

Tags: notation

I want to show square of a logarithm function. I can write it in $2$ ways:

First: $\ln^2(x), \log^2x$

Second:$(\ln(x))^2, (\log x)^2$

The first one is easier to use. Is it ok or we should use second one? what about $\log^x_k$ is it better to write as $(\log^x_k)^2$?

Comment: Is $\log^x_k$ a typo? Else this is the worst notation I have ever seen, and should never be used. Otherwise the first two notations are understood, even tho some might struggle with the first one, as it can be confused with $\ln(\ln(x))$. I prefer the second notation.

Comment: $\log^ x_k$ is meant to be logarithm of $x$ in base of $k$ . what is the problem with that?

Comment: I would make a note at the beginning that $\ln^2x = (\ln x)^2$ (so it would not be confused with repeated application $\ln(\ln x)$) and then use the first notation. The second version has too much visual noise in my opinion.

Comment: The problem with $\log^x_k$ is that it is uncommon and unnatural to look at. Also it is annoying to type.

Comment: @soheil the version $\log _k^x$ is a non-standard notation (I have never seen it personally before today), and it would definitely contribute to confusion.

Comment: This is interesting. first I thought about logarithm our teacher showed it as $\log^x_k$ if I'm not mistaking(it was a long time ago!). then it should be $\log_k x$ am I right?

Comment: $\log^2 x$ is short and common. Definitely OK to use. $(\log x)^2$ is unambiguous and not too uncommon. Also OK to use.

Comment: @DanielFischer is $\ln^2x$ ok and common too?

Comment: If you're talking to physicists, it is. Among mathematicians it would be unusual (but still understood).